# How do I wait till a db query is completed?

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7

Currently I'm executing db queries this way:

```
_svc = new Service1Client();
_svc.GetStateCompleted += new EventHandler<GetStateCompletedEventArgs>(_svc_GetStateCompleted);

    private void _svc_GetStateCompleted(object sender, userdetCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //some code
    }
```

Calling the query function,

```
_svc.GetStateAsync(args);
//more code
```

Is there anyway I can wait after GetStateAsync till the service function returns a value?

Comment: You should be running everything asynchronously and not waiting for something to finish. You can assign the response to an object and then check that for changes instead.

Comment: How these question relate to the Windows Azure platform and SQL Azure? It is general async/sync question and the answer shall be one and the same regardless of the underlying database or platform deployment. 
Plus, working with disconnected clients it is not good idea to block the UI untill something finishes. In general it is not good to block the UI (which happens when you "wait" for something to finish). That is way the async programming is out there for.

Comment: What you have is the correct way. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Please don't put things like " [Windows phone 7]" into your titles. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you do not wait for a long running operation to complete. There are ways to achieve that, but normally if you do not want users to interact with the application until it completes - you disable all inputs and show some sort of a progress indicator until the operation completes.